# Add new users to ActiveMQ Artemis instance

Tags: roles, activemq-artemis

I create an ActiveMQ Artemis broker with a user (`system`) and password (`systempass`). The broker assigns a role to this user and the broker instance `artemis-users.properties` and `artemis-roles.properties` are updated accordingly

I then create new users & roles for the broker instance as follows:

```
./artemis user add --user-command-user guest --user-command-password guest --role amq --user system --password systempass
```

The broker's `artemis-users.properties` and `artemis-roles.properties` are not updated with the new user, password, and role. Is this a problem?

Comment: The user add command updates artemis-users.properties and artemis-roles.propertie. What ActiveMQ Artemis version are you using? Is the activemq-artemis broker running while you was executing the user add command?

Comment: Hi Justin... Yes the broker is running and my version is latest version.. I will look at it again now I know that user add command should. Update the properties filed

Comment: When you say "latest version" do you mean 2.21.0 which was just released?

Comment: Can you paste your `etc/login.config` and `etc/bootstrap.xml`?

Comment: Are you still hitting this issue?

Comment: No.. I have to use an artemis image developed by other team.. I am not creating the broker instance any longer... I can configure the broker. Xml through configmap but I cannot add users except maybe through a deployment hook but for now I am not going to do that